# PHP - Convert this string to another date/time format

Tags: php, datetime

I'm working with an API that returns timestamps in this format:

```
07/23/2017 23:39:21
```

The format is: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS

I need to covert this string so it displays in this format on my webpage:

23 July 2017, 11:39pm

Is this possible?

Comment: Certainly this is possible. You can do that yourself. You just need one or two lines of code in PHP.

Comment: The answer to the question "Is it possible?" is almost always "yes". What did you try?

Comment: Look into using the `DateTime` PHP class.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @arkascha I know that, not sure why I wrote object. Fixed :]

Comment: Just bumped into this so sharing https://stdlib.com/serkanyersen/date-parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
$date = new DateTime('07/23/2017 23:39:21');
echo $date->format('d F o, h:ia');
```

Output :

`23 July 2017, 11:39pm`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.createfromformat.php. You'll get a DateTime object which you can convert in the format you desire.

Like so:

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:i:s', '07/23/2017 23:39:21');
echo $date->format('d M Y, h:ia');
?>
```

Comment: It's preferable to answer the question not just refer. Copy the relevant parts